# how to create a loop function to sum array data based on increasing index in php

Tags: php

Excuse me, I want to ask about the iteration step.

i have $data like this

```
array:6 [▼
      0 => 0
      1 => 0.25
      2 => 0.75
      3 => 0.5
      4 => 0.5
      5 => 0.75
]
```

but i want to make iteration or loop $result like below

```
$result[0]=2.75
$result[1]=2.75
$result[2]=2.5
$result[3]=1.75
$result[4]=1.25
$result[5]=0.75
```

result explanation

```
$result[0]= 0 + 0.25 + 0.75 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.75 = 2.75
$result[1]= 0.25 + 0.75 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.75 = 2.75
$result[2]= 0.75 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.75 = 2.5
$result[3]= 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.75 = 1.75
$result[4]= 0.5 + 0.75 = 1.25
$result[5]= 0.75 = 0.75
```

I've tried several times to make this loop function, but it doesn't work, here's my latest code

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
              if (isset($data[$i + 1])) {
                     $result += $data[$i + 1];
             } else {
                 $result += 0;
          }
    }
```

What is the correct looping function to get the expected result, please help, thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh thanks for the advice, sorry for my previous mistake, I've changed the question to make it easier to understand, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) along with [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php

$array  = [
      0 => 0,
      1 => 0.25,
      2 => 0.75,
      3 => 0.5,
      4 => 0.5,
      5 => 0.75
];

$finalArray = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$arr){
    $finalArray[] = ($key > 0) ? array_sum(array_slice($array,$key)) : array_sum($array);
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

https://3v4l.org/LU63i

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to loop from the end to the beginning of the array – it would be way faster with longer arrays:

```
$data = [ 0, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75 ];

$sum = 0;
for ($i = count($data) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $sum += $data[$i];
  $data[$i] = $sum;
}

print_r($data);
```

This is not to diminish @Anant's answer, as it is totally fine for short arrays, but calling *array_sum* and *array_slice* for each entry leads to the following time differences compared to a solution which just keeps a running sum:

```
    10 elements: ~2 times slower
   100 elements: ~5 times slower
  1000 elements: ~85 times slower
 10000 elements: ~750 times slower
100000 elements: ~8800 times slower
```

Comment: Wow, that's great information, I was stuck at first not knowing how to solve it. It turns out that there are many ways that can be used, thank you very much for answering